# Create SQL Server View with progressive field only regarding some other fields

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's assume I have a table like this one below:

[image]

Now, from that table I would like to create a view like this one below:

[image]

Number is a progressive counter per EventId, for example, first row with EventId EVENT1 has Number equals to 1, second row with EventId EVENT1 has Number equals to 2, and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EventId ORDER BY TimeStamp)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Row_number()

```
   declare @myt table
(eventid nvarchar(50),userid nvarchar(50),timestamps datetime)

insert into @myt
values
('Event1','User1','2017-10-30 00:00:01.000'),
('Event2','User2','2017-10-30 00:00:10.000'),
('Event1','User2','2017-10-30 00:00:11.000'),
('Event3','User2','2017-10-30 00:00:12.000'),
('Event2','User1','2017-10-30 00:00:10.000'),
('Event3','User1','2017-10-30 00:00:11.000')


select *,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by eventid order by timestamps) from @myt
order by timestamps
```

You dont need the last order by, but thats so it looks like your example.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
SELECT *
    ,SUM(1) OVER(PARTITION BY eventid ORDER BY userid,timestamps) Number
FROM Your_Table
ORDER BY timestamps
```